# Android camera preview vs background service

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

If I run an image processing app on Android, which will be better in terms of memory/cpu usage and heating issue?

1. Run camera with the preview.
2. Run camera in a background service. [This](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization.html)  says background service takes up a lot of memory( I used to think opposite ).

The reason I ask this is because I want to run the app 24/7, but I'm not sure which approach will be better with my purpose. I did test my app running camera with the preview and it stop due to heat after like 1 week.

Thanks.

Comment: To keep the device from heat, turn the screen off.

Comment: That's a good point. Thanks. What about leaving the app by pressing home button? Does it help too?

Comment: It will probably disconnect the camera

Comment: I managed to run the camera and image processing part in the background service, so it's not the case.

Comment: @AlexCohn update
The app runs on LG G4 using Camera2 interface and do image processing in the background with the screen off, got too hot and the phone turned off itself after a few hours. What can I do to overcome this?

Comment: I would look into reducing CPU usage, e.g.  process 1 frame per second, or even less, if possible. Alternatively, install cold fan next to the device; take the cover off and detach the battery to get the electronics better ventilated

Comment: @AlexCohn Thanks a lot for all inputs.

Comment: @AlexCohn 
1 frame per second => I can't as I need at least 12fps( Currently it runs at 22+ fps as I use raw format. Will reducing fps help? )

Detach the battery => what do u mean by this? 
Again thank you very much.

Comment: @AlexCohn Also, how come when I test opening the native camera app, it even runs for days without any issue? How come it gets too hot when I use Camera2 interface? I use raw format, then renderscript to convert it to rgb. Is that the reason causing overheat?

Comment: I believe that the native camera app does no processing of the frames. Also, if you turn the screen off, the native camera goes to sleep. In your case, any reduction of CPU usage may help. If you simply skip every second frame you receive from the camera, going down to 12 FPS, the device may overheat significantly less.

Comment: "detach battery" - see http://i67.tinypic.com/2e33ec8.png. You can also connect the battery with wires, to allow even more ventilation for the motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen uses a lot of power, so leave it off if at all possible.

The camera API itself doesn't care if you're in a foreground app or in a background service, but the more simultaneous outputs you request, the higher the power consumption will likely be.  Similarly, the higher the output resolutions you ask for are, the higher the power consumption.

You can have a foreground app with no preview, if you're using camera2; even with camera1, you can just add a dummy SurfaceTexture member to your activity/etc and set it as the preview target, so that you don't pay the cost of actual GPU activity.

That still has the overhead of the camera API pushing pointless images to that SurfaceTexture, which you can only avoid with camera2.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously running camera continuously for a long time in preview mode made your device warm even if U have a high configuration device.In my suggestion You can tolerate the memory issue but not heating issue because it leads to many other harmful issue in your device(due to over heating).So go for background service,hope this will not heated your device as comparison to preview mode .

Comment: Thanks Neo, I'm developing the second version using Camera2 and running in the background service. I'm experiencing some issues too but I'm trying to tackle one by one. I will test more and come back if I hit any serious issue. Thanks again.